# FreeIPA refuses to sign a VMWare certificate signing request (CSR)

Tags: certificate, vmware-vcenter, freeipa, x509

I'm attempting to make VMWare's certificate authority (VMCA) v6.7 a trusted sub-CA of a FreeIPA certificate authority. I should be able to generate a certificate signing request within VMCA using either an interactive tool (certificate-manager) or by using VMWare's certool and a config file (certool.cfg).

Of course, interactive tools have their appeal. The tool asks questions. Some answers are required:

```
Press Enter key to skip optional parameters or use Previous value.

Enter proper value for 'Country' [Previous value : US] : 

Enter proper value for 'Name' [Previous value : vcenter.int.demarcohome.com] : 

Enter proper value for 'Organization' [Previous value : DeMarco Home] : 

Enter proper value for 'OrgUnit' [Previous value : none] : 

Enter proper value for 'State' [Previous value : North Carolina] : 

Enter proper value for 'Locality' [Previous value : Raleigh] : 

Enter proper value for 'IPAddress' (Provide comma separated values for multiple IP addresses) [optional] : 

Enter proper value for 'Email' [Previous value : nick@demarcohome.com] : 

Enter proper value for 'Hostname' (Provide comma separated values for multiple Hostname entries) [Enter valid Fully Qualified Domain Name(FQDN), For Example : example.domain.com] : vcenter.int.demarcohome.com

Enter proper value for VMCA 'Name' : vcenter
```

Within FreeIPA, when I attempt to sign this CSR, the request is not signed, with error #3009:

```
invalid 'csr': subject alt name type RFC822Name is forbidden for non-user principals
```

Decoding the CSR (https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html) tells me it includes subject alternate names (SANs):

```
email:nick@demarcohome.com,
IP Address:10.71.73.8
vcenter.int.demarcohome.com
```

The error 'Name is forbidden for non-user principals' makes some sense to me, but not enough to point me in the right direction. Do I need to format my CSR differently by answering the questions differently, or am I going about the process of creating a subordinate CA incorrectly within FreeIPA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common names used as Subject Alternative Name (SAN) in an X.509 v3 certificate extension are 'DNSName' and 'RFC822Name'. The name 'RFC822Name' is usually an email address while 'DNSName' is a hostname.

The error "'invalid 'csr': subject alt name type RFC822Name is forbidden for non-user principals'" says it all. You can't use a SAN with name type 'RFC822Name' when you request a certificate for a non-user principal.

It seems you are trying to create a certificate for a certificate authority (CA). In this case you used the wrong certificate profile to create the certificate signing request (CSR). I would recommend to talk to your PKI administrators and explain them that you want to create CSR for a CA and ask them which profile to use. Different types of certificates require different profiles because of the different extensions used in the certificates.

You can find more information about how to make VMCA a intermediate CA here:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-886C7657-3C2D-4AAC-8525-D5700CA58FCD.html

And here you see the requirements for the CSR to make VMCA a intermediate CA:

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-75008746-C902-4C42-8F5C-6602D6E4EC8B.html#GUID-75008746-C902-4C42-8F5C-6602D6E4EC8B

Comment: Your answer is helpful. I'm the PKI administrator, and also the person who takes out the trash. Please guide me on a few more points. Future me update my question.

Comment: The article for making a VSphere 6.7 VMCA an intermediate CA is https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.psc.doc/GUID-5FE583A2-3737-4B62-A905-5BB38D479AE0.html

Comment: On certificate profiles, please share some starting points for learning about certificate profiles.

Comment: I would recommend to check the product documentation first. Other than that I think a good starting point is to read rfc5280 and the openssl-req man page. There you will find more information about how to create a CSR using openssl and how to make sure the correct certificate extensions are added to the CSR. Check for 'v3_ca' configuration profile to see which extensions are required when you create a CSR for a Certificate Authority.

Comment: I thank you for taking time to write this. It is, however, not a realistic task. FreeIPA's documentation is scattered, full of superseded info, and written for a deeply technical audience, contrary to the product's stated goal. RFC5280 is 147 pages of dense material. In my experience, this will raise many more questions than it will answer. It's not my intention to become an expert in the field of PKI. Can you point me to a profile you believe I should be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this problem is to update the template so that it is not asking for the email address.

The base template is here:
`/usr/lib/vmware-vmca/share/config/certool.cfg`

If you have already run the tool, the system uses the copy in: `/var/tmp/vmware/certool.cfg`

You can change the file to look like:

```
#
# Template file for a CSR request
#

# Country is needed and has to be 2 characters
Country = US
Name    = CA
Organization = VMware
OrgUnit = VMware Engineering
State = California
Locality = Palo Alto
IPAddress = 127.0.0.1
#Email = email@acme.com
Hostname = server.acme.com
```

This will create a CSR that can be signed by IPA and used by vcenter.